# Solving "DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application." for Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I installed Python 3.1 and the Pygame module for Python 3.1.  When I type `import python` in the console I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Comment: More details: [\[SO\]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: \[WinError 193\] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546).

Answer (score 149, accepted):

It could be due to the architecture of your OS. Is your OS 64 Bit and have you installed 64 bit version of Python? It may help to install both 32 bit version [Python 3.1](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.1.3/python-3.1.3.msi) and [Pygame](http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1.win32-py3.1.msi), which is available officially only in 32 bit and you won't face this problem.

I see that 64 bit pygame is maintained [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame), you might also want to try uninstalling Pygame only and install the 64 bit version on your existing python3.1, if not choose go for both 32-bit version.

Comment: This hits the nail on the head for wxpython too :)

Comment: also works for getting PIL module working in GAE dev_appserver on Windows 7

Comment: I got a similar error when installing pygame for Python 3.2 on a system with Python 3.4 installed (both 32 bit). The pygame website didn't provide a newer version, but it was available [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)!

Comment: @SenthilKumaran, If I have 64-bit Windows and Install 32-python and 32-libs, shoul I have this problem? I can't install `numpy+mkl` to use `sklearn`

Comment: Great man, I ran into this when I stupidly decided that using pycharm would be a great idea.Everything was perfect before installing it.After installing it.My django server won't. Thanks you.Its working again.

Answer (score 9):

Looks like the question has been long ago answered but the solution did not work for me.  When I was getting that error, I was able to fix the problem by downloading [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

Answer (score 3):

I had installed Python 32 bit version and psycopg2 64 bit version to get this problem. I installed psycopg2 32 bit version and then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue on Python 2.7.9, solved by updating to Python 2.7.10 (unreleased when this question was asked and answered).

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause of similar issue could be wrong `processorArchitecture` in the cx_freeze manifest, trying to load x86 common controls dll in x64 process - should be fixed by this patch:

https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-request/71/changed-x86-in-windows-manifest-to/diff