# DLL load failed: 1% is not valid win32 application

Tags: wxpython

> ```
> import wx
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in 
>     import wx
>   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\__init__.py", line 45, in 
>     from wx._core import *
>   File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode\wx\_core.py", line 4, in 
>     import _core_
> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
> ```

I have tried python2.6 and python2.7 with several wxpython versions,they all turned out to be like this.All the versions are win64 as well as my OS,please hep!

Comment: When you start the python interpreter, does the first message show `64 bit (AMD64)` or `32 bit (Intel)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving “DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.” for Pygame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676433/solving-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-for-pygame)?

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned by the other fellow, make sure you have a 64-bit Python AND a 64-bit wxPython version downloaded. If one or the other is 32-bit, it won't work. Personally, I have never had any problems installing wxPython on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in windows 7 with `Python2.7` as I have installed 32bit wx version earlier. Try installing 64bit and it will work fine.If you are in 64 bit system and trying to install 32bit wx you will get some error at the beginning. So try 64bit wx.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that your py shell version (win32 or win64).
   when you open idle. it will display the version.
2. Download the wxpython for win32 and install.
   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wxPython