# Error with wxpython demo file

Tags: python, wxpython

I recently downloaded and installed the files "wxPython2.8-win64-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27… and "wxPython2.8-win32-docs-demos-2.8.12.1.e… However when I click on the menu item for the demo, nothing happens. When I follow the link to "C:\Program Files (x86)\wxPython2.8 Docs and Demos\demo\demo.pyw" and try to run it in the python IDLE, I get a error. Dose anyone have an idea what I can do to get the demo and library working?

Error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqIio.png

[image]

Menu item: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf6dA.jpg

[image]

Computer info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObGUg.png

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277875/dll-load-failed-1-is-not-valid-win32-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your wxpython version is 64 bits, and the demo 32.
If you want to use the demo, make sure that your python installation and your wxpython are both 32bits. (i.e. reinstall python and wxpython in the 32bits versions)