# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application (wx._core_)

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

So i just started learning python and i'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHvhfjVpSdE#t=274 . But i keep geting this error.

This is my code:

```
import wx

class bucky(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id, 'Frame aka window', size=(300, 200))

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=bucky(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/gui.py", line 1, in <module>
    import wx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\_core.py", line 4, in <module>
    import _core_
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 er ikke et gyldig Win32-program.
```

Please help!

Comment: Can you translate the error to English? Seems like it's related to your operating system.

Comment: ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 er ikke et gyldig Win32-program. = importerror: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid win32-program

Comment: Probably just *Bla is not a valid win32 application*

Comment: Could it be that wherever you picked up `wx` for the wrong OS?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741786/dll-load-failure-error-in-wxpython

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe wrong installer, on Windows you have to ensure that if you installed Python 2.7 32 then you need to use a wxPython 3.0 for Python 2.7 32 bit.

Instead of using 3.0 you might want to use the preview build for 3.0.1 which you can find here:
http://wxpython.kosoftworks.com/preview/20140707/