# trouble importing pygame in python 3.4

Tags: python, pygame

I installed pygame using pip, but when i try to import it, it gives me this error. What could be the possible problem ?

*update, i downloaded a 32 bit version of pygame, extract it to python directory\Lib\site-packages and it's working now

[image]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676433/solving-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-for-pygame

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the bits of python you are working and the package doesn't match. It seems you are working in a 64-bit python and you have installed 32-bit python pygame package. you can find the 64-bit pygame package [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)