# ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application, Windows 10

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to get PyGame up and running on Python 3.2. When I try to import it I get

```
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I saw this, which indicated the problem was most likely that the Python and PyGame installations were incompatible (64-bit of one, 32-bit of the other), but I have the 32 bit versions of both and it's still giving me the error!
I am on Windows 10 (64 bit), Python 3.2 (32 bit), PyGame (32 bit.)
I copied this from another forum, with a minor change (Python 3.4 -> 3.2) The file is named the same as the appropriate file from @muratgu's link.

Comment: have you tried http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame ?

Comment: @numbermaniac He's using Python 3.1, and none of his answers work. In fact, I checked that question before making this one.

Comment: @hawk468 Add the previous comment in your post. (I have looked at this .... But it does not work as .... )

Comment: [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676433/solving-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-for-pygame) post should do your job.