# Python 3 installing javabridge, DLL load failed error

Tags: python, dll, weka

I want to use [python-weka-wrapper3](http://pythonhosted.org/python-weka-wrapper3/index.html) for my project. To install it, first I should install javabridge. But when I try **pip install javabridge-1.0.14-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl** I got **javabridge-1.0.14-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.** For this I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568070/filename-whl-is-not-supported-wheel-on-this-platform/37046355) solution and dowloaded 32 bit version of javabridge (Note: I'm using python 3.5.2). After running program, I got an error like **ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.** and tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676433/solving-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-for-pygame) solution. But it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: do you have a 32 bit version of python or 64?

Comment: I have 32 bit .

Comment: have you set the path to JAVA ?

Comment: Yess (Why stackoverflow asks at least 15 characters)

Comment: have you found the solution for this problem??

Comment: @mina actually I don't remember how I solved this problem, sorry :(

Comment: has anyone managed to solve this problem? I have encoutnered the same one:(